# Safari doesn't respect input type accept extension

Tags: html, safari

When I give the following extension for input file type, Safari doesn't consider that at all.
Below is the example what I tried

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" accept=".pdf"/>
```

File browse window in Safari shows all the extensions and not just ".pdf". Is this is the expected behaviour? I'm using the latest version of Safari on Mac OSX ElCapitan.
An example is available here https://jsfiddle.net/596pgdkn/

Comment: have you tried using the mime type?

Comment: Mime type works. But as per the documentation in w3schools, file extension should be supported http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

Comment: @Apps so should be supported input color, or [WebAudio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), or a lot of other proposed API that aren't supported. Welcome to web-dev.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the mime type form. As of this writing, Safari does not support extensions. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept

Comment: which is `application/pdf` for .pdf  files